# View 1000x1000 on initWithCoder:

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiview, initwithcoder

There are a couple of questions asking this on SO but none have asked that properly.

I am using a custom progress bar that is a `UIView` based class with this implementation.

```
@implementation MCProgressBarView {
    UIImageView * _backgroundImageView;
    UIImageView * _foregroundImageView;
    CGFloat minimumForegroundWidth;
    CGFloat availableWidth;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
  self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
  // [self bounds] is 1000x1000 here... what? 
  if (self) [self initialize];
  return self;
}


- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) [self initialize];
    return self;
}

- (void) initialize {
  UIImage * backgroundImage = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"progress-bg" ofType:@"png"]]
                               resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f)];

  UIImage * foregroundImage = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"progress-bg" ofType:@"png"]]
                               resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f)];

  _backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
  _backgroundImageView.image = backgroundImage;
  [self addSubview:_backgroundImageView];

  _foregroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
  _foregroundImageView.image = foregroundImage;
  [self addSubview:_foregroundImageView];

  UIEdgeInsets insets = foregroundImage.capInsets;
  minimumForegroundWidth = insets.left + insets.right;

  availableWidth = self.bounds.size.width - minimumForegroundWidth;

  [self adjustProgress:0.0f];
}
```

I have created a `UIView` on interface builder to be 200x20 points and assigned that view to be of this custom class `MCProgressBarView` I am using. When the app runs, `initWithCoder` runs and creates a progress view with a size of 1000x1000 points, disregarding the size that the view has on IB.

How do I force initWithCoder to run with the proper size assigned on IB?

NOTE: I don't want to hard wire that to 200x20 and I don't want to set this by code at run time. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Move your frame/bounds logic to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

`initWithCoder:` is not safe for performing frame logic. You should use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` for that. Apple uses 1000x1000 bounds starting with iOS 10. It is unclear if bug or intentional, but it seems to have a net positive outcome - people come here and ask about it. `;-)`

In fact, `initWithCoder:` has never been safe for such logic. In the past, you'd have a view whose bounds would be those of iPhone 5's screen because that was what you used in IB, but then the view would grow to iPhone 6 Plus size or iPad size, and it would cause visual issues.

Now, Apple just sets the bounds to 1000x1000, which is incorrect for all cases. The bounds are corrected once a layout pass is performed on the view.

Comment: There is no viewDidLayoutSubviews on a UIView based class. If I use the viewController to set the view size correctly then this whole thing is poorly conceived by Apple as a lot of things on ios.

Comment: @SpaceDog Use `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: Ok. I have implemented a `layoutSubviews` on the class. When that method runs, the view is with the correct size without I having to do anything but when it displays on the application it is 1000x1000.

Comment: Please post screenshots. Something sounds strange.